# Django admin - prevent objects being saved, and don't show the user confirmation message

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to prevent admins modifying certain data in django. I've done this, but when the user hits 'save', the data is correctly not saved, but the 'success' message is displayed at the top telling the user the data was updated. How can I replace this message?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the messages framework.

In an admin action:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ....
    def foo_action(self, request, queryset):
        ....
        self.message_user(request, "%s foo objects were not saved" % foos_not_saved)
```

In a (model)form:

```
def save(*args, **kwargs):
    # do stuff
    self.message_user(request, "%s fields were not saved" % ','.join(fields_not_saved))
```

Comment: Could you clarify this?  Where is the part that actually prevents the default success message from being displayed?

Comment: @Shanyu Can u please tell me how to restrict the admin form to prevent from saving data if any error is shown

Answer (score 0):

I believe the message is just js.  The javascript for the admin site lives in `djangoX.X/django/contrib/admin/media/js/` and I believe you can change the message in `actions.js`.

Alternatively you can go into `djangoX.X/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/` and over ride the js from there.

Comment: I don't want to change the message everywhere, just where the action isn't permitted.